# Chossing a prime for fft of size $2^n$

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I have a $p$ degree polynomial where $p$ is prime, I want to find the value of this polynomial at all points from $1$ to $p-1$,to make the  fft on this polynomial  easier I padded it with zeroes up to length  to the next power of $2$ greater than p(note that here $p$ and $n$ are both large, the padded length is $2^{20}$  here $p-1$ is a multiple of power of $2$), now I should find the value of this polynomial from $0$  to $2^{20}-1$ but since $2^{20}$ has no primitive root, I cannot do fft on this size. So my question is how do I proceed.  I tried finding primitive root of  $2^{20}$ modulo some prime $p_2$ of the form  $k\cdot 2^{20} +1$, but doing so, the $n$ powers of that primitive root${}^k$  did not give me all values from $0$ to $n-1$. How should I deal with this problem? Although my approach might be wrong new methods are welcome, the original goal is to find value of the polynomial at all points from $0$ to $p-1$ in time $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: What is $n$ here? The first mention of it is that it is large

Comment: n here is the padded length of 2^20

Comment: Ah, so with $n\approx 2p$ we have $n=O(p)$ and so your really original goal is $O(p\log p)$, I presume

Comment: yes that is my primary goal!

Comment: That's an ambitious goal. Merely writing out $p$ values in the range $0,\ldots,p-1$ takes $O(p\log p)$ time.

Comment: do you mean the number theoretic transform ? (the discrete Fourier transform of size $N$ in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, replacing $\omega_N = e^{-2 i \pi / N}$ by a $N$th primitive root of unity)

Comment: that is what I mean

Comment: and you mean $q$ prime and $N = q-1$, so that $\omega_N$ generates $\mathbb{F}_q^*$, and with $P(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{d} a(n) x^n$, $\ d \le q-1$ you have to find $k$ such that $x \equiv \omega_N^k \bmod q$ and you get $A(k) = NTT[a](k) =\sum_{n=0}^{d} \omega_N^{nk} a(n) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{d} x^n a(n) \equiv P(x) \bmod q$

Comment: yes, You interpreted it correctly

Comment: what you wrote is highly unclear. Note you can replace $q$ prime by $q = p^m$ where $p$ is an odd prime, assuming you are an expert of $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$  and its (cyclic) multiplicative group (what you wrote let us think you wanted $q = 2^m$ which doesn't work)

Comment: then what is the other way to do it

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood your comment , I get you now .

Comment: of course, with the NTT you'll never get $P(x)$ but only $P(x) \bmod q$. If you know $P(x) \ge 0$ (for example if all the coefs $a(n)$ are non negative) then you can choose $q > \max_{0 < x < m} P(x)$ and  compute $P(x)$ for $0 < x < m$

Comment: how exactly can you do that , can you discribe your approach in the answer

Comment: is it a joke ? can you describe what you want to do